# Hibernate connection with postgresql on vps not working

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

in my local server hibernate connection with
 postgresql working fine but on vps it is not working.

what can i do??

Thanks

Comment: What about you give some more information? You tell nothing about how you configure the connection etc; no one can guess that for you

Comment: Did you tried anything if Yes What?

Comment: now  i connect my code to mysql and its work fine on vps but when i connect the postgresql it is note working.

Comment: In Postgresql when i see the log that time .. when hibernate code tried to open sessionfactory connection it stop their ....in log nothing print and site goes to blank page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `pg_hba.conf` for allowed hosts for connection. Under VPN you obviously have another IP then in local network.